# Split a complex string using RegEx in c#

Tags: c#, regex

i have to split a string into an array, splitting on \r\n. I want to use Regex, but the following includes any \r\n at the begining or at the end of the string:

```
RegEx.Split(stringIn, @"\r\n")
```

the string i am passing in looks like :

```
"\r\n4:\r\n:20:00412\r\n:21:123456/DEV\r\n:13C:/A234567Z/1359+0100\r\n:32A:\r\n"
```

So this needs to be output into an array as :

```
4:
20:00412
:21:123456/DEV
.
.
:32A:
```

etc

Comment: Why not .Split(Environment.NewLine, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)?

Comment: Removed my answer, misunderstood what you were after, sorry =D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `Trim` the unwanted characters from both ends of your string before passing it for splitting using the `Trim` method, like this:

```
var trimmed = stringIn.Trim(new[] {'\n', '\r'});
```

now the result of the `Split` would no longer have the unwanted characters on either end:

```
var tokens = RegEx.Split(trimmed, @"\r\n")
```

Comment: Perfect dasblinkenlight, i shall run through some tests, but so far so good - thanks