# Split a complex string in C

Tags: c, string, split

Ok, so what I need to do is split a string. Here is an example string that I need to split:

```
test_french_fries
```

and let's say I want to split the string into two parts, the part before and after:

`french`

thus I would get a return of something like:

```
match[1]=[test_]
match[2]=[_fries]
```

I have tried messing around with `strtok()` but I have had no success with that. It appears that `strtok()` splits the string at all delims that are given - so if I were to give it a delim of `french`, it would separate the string for each character matched - which ISN'T what I want.

I would like to have a delim where I can provide it a str or char* such as "french" and the string be split before and after the string provided.

Are there any other methods besides `strtok()` that I could possibly try to implement in order to achieve my desired outcome?

I really appreciate any and all help that I receive.

-Patrick

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17250526/split-a-complex-string-using-regex-in-c-sharp

Comment: @catalyst - this is not a C# question...this is regular C

Comment: Related answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14867292/156811

Comment: There is nothing stopping you re-adding the delimiter after you've split the string up.

Comment: You can just find the substring and get the index. so the two strings would be string 1) pos 0 to index; and string 2) will be (index + strlen(delimiter)) to end.

Comment: Did you consider actually err.. writing some code to do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`strtok()` can only split using a single symbol as separator (1 character), you can specify multiple separators in the form of a null-terminated string, but they are delt with individualy. To split a string with another string as separator, you will have to write a custom function. The example below works just like `strtok()`, but uses a null-terminated C string as separator:

```
#include <stdio.h>

char *strstrtok(char *src, char *sep)
{
    static char *str = NULL;
    if (src) str = src;
    else src = str;

    if (str == NULL)
        return NULL;

    char *next = strstr(str, sep);
    if (next)
    {
        *next = '\0';
        str = next + strlen(sep);
    }
    else
        str = NULL;

    return src;
}

int main(void) {
    char buf[] = "yoursepmamasepissepsosepfatsepsheseptooksepasepspoonseptosepthesepsuperbowl";
    char *token = strstrtok(buf, "sep");
    while (token)
    {
        printf("%s ", token);
        token = strstrtok(NULL, "sep");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Notice just like `strtok()`, this solution is not thread-safe.

See it working on Ideone: http://ideone.com/cjRGgJ

Comment: better to use `strtok_r` as the model and take an extra `save` pointer, rather than using a non-reentrant/thread safe static var...

Comment: Yes, this is perfect. I had just started to write something like this, but yours is exactly what I need.